# ¿Como cambio el texto de un label cuando ejecute la aplicacion en mi celular en App Inventor?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, appinventor

Estoy creando una aplicación android con App Inventor que se comunica mediante bluetooth a un Arduino, el problema esta en que tengo unos label y quiero que el usuario puede modificarlos a su gusto cuando use la aplicación en su móvil.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los label que quiero que se puedan editar son los que dicen dispositivo 1,dispositivo 2 y así sucesivamente

La verdad no se como hacerlo, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida

Comment: y como el usuario realizaría la edición?  porque no lo comentas en tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia,  quisiera que el usuario mantenga presionado el label y le aparezca una ventana emergente o que se abra otra ventana y alli se pueda editar, no tengo la mas minima idea y ya no se como buscar en google y en los foros

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo podrias hacer de esta manera, desde inicio la aplicacion en el modo diseño o mediante codigo de bloque.

[image: modo diseñador]

[image: modo bloque de codigo]